# DC.js - Select Menu as a filter for Composite charts

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, composite, jquery-ui-selectmenu

My dataset is similar to [this](https://github.com/JaelB/Generic-DC.js-Chart/blob/master/fiddle2.csv).

```
name,code,proc,subP,date,m,a,b,o,t
BW,1333,29,1,2015-12-29 02:30:00,10,0,0,0,10
BW,1333,29,1,2015-12-29 12:00:00,25,0,0,0,25
BW,1333,29,1,2015-12-30 12:00:00,26,0,0,0,26
BW,1333,29,2,2015-12-31 12:00:00,27,0,0,0,27
BW,1333,29,2,2016-01-01 12:00:00,26.1,4.9,1.8,0,32.8
BW,1333,29,2,2016-01-02 12:00:00,26.4,4.9,1.9,0,33.2
BW,1333,29,2,2016-01-03 12:00:00,26.2,4.9,1.9,0,33
...
NS,1212,11,1,2016-07-28 15:30:00,1.6,3.7,4.4,0,9.7
NS,1212,11,1,2016-07-29 12:00:00,17.4,2.3,0,0,19.7
NS,1212,11,1,2016-07-30 12:00:00,21,5,14.1,0,40.1
NS,1212,11,2,2016-07-31 11:12:00,18.1,3.5,6.1,0,27.7
NS,1212,11,2,2016-07-31 12:00:00,0.1,0.2,0.2,0,0.5
NS,1212,11,2,2016-08-01 12:00:00,0.1,2.7,2.6,0,5.4
```

I'm using a composite line chart to represent this data.

I'm using selectMenu to filter 'BW' and 'NS' records. But the composite chart remains unchanged when I use selectmenu.

I split the data into two seperate files (one with 'BW' records and the other with 'NS' records) to try to implement the data selection functionality provided in [dc.js Series Chart example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/series.html) . That didnt work either.

[Here is a fiddle with one of the charts.](http://jsfiddle.net/JaelB/ehLvdb07/27/)

Ultimately, I would like to filter multiple charts(composite, series and bubble)  by 'BW' and 'NS' records with or without a select menu.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with your selectMenu or your composite chart, it's with the way you are reducing data.

The first parameter to [group.reduce()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce) is the add function, the second parameter is the remove function, and the final one is the initialize function.

You usually don't want to set `p` directly from `v` as you are doing:

```
var grp = dim.group().reduce(
          function(p,v){
            p.m = +v.m;
            p.a = +v.a;
            p.b = +v.b;
            return p;
          },
          function(p,v){
            p.m = +v.m;
            p.a = +v.a;
            p.b = +v.b;
            return p;
          },
          function(){return {m:0, a:0, b:0}; });
```

That will only work if every key is perfectly unique and no two items ever fall in the same bin.

And you almost never want to set `p` from `v` in the remove function. That will prevent anything from ever being removed.

Instead, add and subtract the values like so:

```
var grp = dim.group().reduce(
          function(p,v){
            p.m = p.m + +v.m;
            p.a = p.a + +v.a;
            p.b = p.b + +v.b;
            return p;
          },
          function(p,v){
            p.m = p.m - +v.m;
            p.a = p.a - +v.a;
            p.b = p.b - +v.b;
            return p;
          },
          function(){return {m:0, a:0, b:0}; });
```

Here's a [working fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/e9na3c6o/15/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Gordon. I have simply been using reduce whenever I wanted to group multiple columns without giving it much thought. I will keep this in mind from next time.